# Java JPA transaction insert/update does not insert/update into DB immediately

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a service::method that inserts the entities into DB using the JPARepository but when just after the repo.saveAll if I make a select statement it returns empty.

Here is the setup:
Router.java

```
Class Router {
    @Autowired
    private IDataService service;

    void addData(List<Data> datas) {
     
      // insert the data into table
      service.add(datas);
      

      // try to see if there its inserted into DB
      try {
            Connection conn = dbManager.getConnection(DBAccess.READONLY);
            
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data_table");
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                // is empty
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Services.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Services implements IDataService {
    
    @Autowired
    private IDataRepository dataRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Data> add(List<Data> datas) {
        return dataRepo.saveAll(datas);
    }
}
```

IDataRepository.java

```
public interface IDataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, String> {
}
```

Since service::add is transactional we should have JPA committing and flushing it and hence the next call at the router to get the data from DB using DBManager should work.

But its not working :( is there something I need to do get this working?

Comment: Why is `@Transactional` used on Class level and also on method level? Further why is saveAll marked as transactional?

Comment: Further: Did you used the correct import for `@Transactional` ? Should be `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. I mix them up some times (can't edit anymore)